# Input string replacing by '+' with whitespace

Tags: php, web-services, rest, joomla

I testing my web service with Google Chrome's Advanced REST client extension,
When I send value in description input box (for e.g. "this is my test"),
and in web service it is saved in database. But it saves the string as "this+is+my+test".
The web service is in php & joomla.

My code for getting the post value in web service.

```
$getData = JRequest::get('post');
$description = $getData['description'];

// $description  contains "this+is+my+test"
```

I want the string as it is.
Can anyone tell me what is the issue ?

Comment: Try `$description = urldecode($getData['description']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$description = urldecode($getData['description']);`

This would work.

Comment: Would be nice if you also recomemnd him to use JInput instead of JRequest. JRequest is deprecated.